# PB / SQLite3 JOIN TABLES

Tags: php, sqlite, join

I have create 3 tables, and I want data of the 3

T1

- idt1 - PRIMARY KEY
- n1t1
- n2t1

T2

- idt2 - PRIMARY KEY
- n1t2
- n2t2

T3

- idt3
- idt1 - FOREIGN KEY
- idt2 - FOREIGN KEY
- n1t3
- n2t3
- n3t3
- n4t3

I search this informations : n1t1, n2t1, n1t2, n1t3, n2t3

Code :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t1.n1t1 AS t1_n1t1, t1.n2t1 AS t1_n2t1, t2.n1t2 AS t2_n1t2, t3.n1t3 AS t3_n1t3, t3.n2t3 AS t3_n2t3
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.idt1 = t3.idt1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.idt2 = T2.idt2
");

if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {
    $arr = $result->fetchArray();
    foreach ($arr as &$row) {
      echo "1 : " .  $row["t1_n1t1"] . "<br>";
      echo "2 : " .  $row["t1_n2t1"] . "<br>";
      echo "3 : " .  $row["t2_n1t2"] . "<br>";
      echo "4 : " .  $row["t3_n1t3"] . "<br>";
      echo "5 : " .  $row["t3_n2t3"] . "<br>";

    }
}
```

Errors :
I have values ​​displayed (1: 2) it varies and above an error
`Warning: Illegal string offset` on somes names as n1T1 ect .

I have see that my idt1 and idt2 (FOREIGN KEY) on t3 have a column name : 0

Screen :

[screen tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3P9p.png)

I insert with a exemple.csv :

```
n1t3;n2t3;n3t3;n4t3
123;n2a;n3a;n4a
456;n2b;n3b;n4b
789;n2c;n3c;n4c
456;n2d;n3d;n4d
```

Code :
I add my FOREINGN KEY in

```
if (($file = fopen('exemple.csv', 'r')) === FALSE)
    echo "SQLite 3 : error CSV";

$req = $db->exec("CREATE TABLE t3 (idt3 integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, idt1 integer, idt2 integer, n1t3, n2t3, n3t3, n4t3 FOREIGN KEY(idT1) REFERENCES t1(idt1), FOREIGN KEY(idt2) REFERENCES t2(idt2))");

$req = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO t3 (idt1, idt2, n1t3, n2t3, n3t3, n4t3) VALUES (:idt1, :idt2, :n1t3, :n2t3, :n3t3, :n4t3)");
 
$idt1 = 0;
$idt2 = 0;

$req->bindValue(':idt1', $idt1++, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$req->bindValue(':idt2', $idt2++, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
...
```

I have retire first line, name table at t1 & t3 for test with it

```
fgetcsv($file);
```

But always the same error code...

New screen tables :

[screen tables v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMESr.png)

Comment: I think that you simplified your code and the columns that you use in the query do not exist in the tables. Edit your question and post the correct code.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS It is hard to follow this layout, it is disorganized. Also it is hard to follow your writing. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS It is best to debug within one layer at a time. Show what each layer gives & gets. PS What is your 1 question?

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you join tables together with the same column name in each, you must prefix the column name with the table name (or alias) , it is a good practice to just use that syntax as a default and ALWAY prefix column names with table names (or aliases)

```
<?php

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT T1.N1 AS T1_N1, T1.N2 AS T1_N2, T2.N1 AS T2_N1, T2.N2 AS T2_N2, T3.N1 AS T3_N1, T3.N2 AS T3_N2
    FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.idT1 = T3.idT1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.idT2 = T2.idT2
");

if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {
    $arr = $result->fetchArray();
    foreach ($arr as &$row) {
      echo "1 : " .  $row["T1_N1"] . "<br>";
      echo "2 : " .  $row["T1_N2"] . "<br>";
      echo "3 : " .  $row["T2_N1"] . "<br>";
      echo "4 : " .  $row["T2_N2"] . "<br>";
      echo "5 : " .  $row["T3_N1"] . "<br>";
      echo "6 : " .  $row["T3_N2"] . "<br>"; 

    }
}
```

Comment: I have test this good method, but I have always this error ```Warning: SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such column: T1.n1T1```

Comment: Ok I have find for what, but now I have this ```Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetch() ``` In start I have ```$db = new SQLite3('exemple.db');```

Comment: The same with ```$req->fetchArray()``` error ```Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetchArray()```

Comment: I have values ​​displayed (1: 2) it varies and above an error ``` Warning: Illegal string offset `` `on somes names as n1T1 ect ..

Comment: Ah ok, I think I see the issue, I thought what you listed above was the column names, changing the code again, but can you please post the table structure of each table ?

Comment: I have update the code, they are columns with title name, and one without, I have add a screen of tables